# migrating data from VSS to SVN

Tags: svn, migration, cvs, visual-sourcesafe

How do i migrate my data from VSS to SubVersion??

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417355/is-there-a-way-to-migrate-sourcesafe-with-history-into-svn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to take the VSS Meta Data with you.

If yes, have a look at [PowerAdmin](http://www.poweradmin.com/sourcecode/vssmigrate.aspx) or [Vss2SVN](http://vss2svn.tigris.org/) on Tigris

If no, just to a search of the Code Folders on your machine to remove all *.scc* & *.vss*
files and then dump that code into your SVN Repo in the standard way.

EDIT:
Looks like Vss2SVN Development on Tigris has been parked.

Answer (score 0):

there's a better migration tool on Codeplex, called (imaginatively) [VSS2SVN](http://vss2svn.codeplex.com/). It works very well, and keeps your history.