# Source Control with Visual Studio Integration (Preferably free)

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

We've been using Visual Source Safe 6.0d for quite some time now, and it has served us well.  However, upon attempting to upgrade to SourceSafe 2005, we discovered that it costs an arm and a leg!  Additionally, it does not appear to be a painless upgrade.  That said, we want a different solution that costs less money (preferrably free).  As long as it has Visual Studio integration, it will work for us.

I've heard that SubVersion with the VisualSVN plugin is a good alternative.  Anybody made this switch before?  If so, how painful was it?

**EDIT:**  We have a small group of developers, less than 10.  We don't need to have source control over the web, it will just be internal.

Comment: How many users, etc.? All in the same place, or distributed? Need web access?

Comment: Great questions, I can't believe I left that out.  Edited!  Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We too were long-time users of Visual SourceSafe 6, and made the switch about 6 months ago to VisualSVN / TortoiseSVN, and we've never looked back. The extra productivity and flexibility its given our team of 4 developers is massive.

There is some getting used to the concepts of branching and merging, but nothing that isn't  covered in the Subversion documentation.

I've found that I often use the TortoiseSVN Windows Explorer integration for most tasks like updating and committing, but VisualSVN is nicely integrated with the IDE and worth the money.

Comment: Thanks!  We've been using it for a few months now and we are all very pleased.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a big fan of [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) + [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) VS Integration.  It's an easy and free setup and so far has been very painless.  [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) as a shell integration is an awesome compliment and well I don't know if you could do without.

Comment: +1 for VisualSVN server, AnkhSVN & TortoiseSVN, we have the same setup here and they are all good.

Comment: Agreed, I really like this setup.

Comment: I believe that the VisualSVN tool is a plug in to Visual Studio that piggy backs on the Tortoise installation.  Not sure if this has changed or not.  No worries though...having Tortoise and the explorer integration makes source control much much easier.  Visual Studio and VisualSVN only allows you to version things that show up in Visual Studio...anything else in the trunk has to be done using Tortoise any how!

Answer (score 3):

I have used SVN for quite some time now and loves it's tight integration with CruiseControl.net regarding automated builds. I had used Tortoise for so long that I was quite comfortable with it's explorer plugins.  However, many of my team members couldn't quite grasp Tortoise and complained constantly.  Then we purchased VisualSVN and got them plugged in on that.  All the pain went away and they were quite happy after that.

WAY BETTER THAN SourceSafe.

Comment: WAY BETTER THAN SourceSafe. -- Just had to reinforce that!

Comment: TeamCity way better than CC. WAY BETTER

Comment: AnkhSVN is a no-licensing-cost plugin for Subversion and Visual Studio and it works very well for my team.

Answer (score 3):

Our shop tried SVN quite a while ago, but after the bugginess we had with it (constantly updating tortoiseSVN, lack of good branching, and some other issues), we started to evaluate other options.

We finally settled on http://www.plasticscm.com/ PlasticSCM, it has some features of git/mercurial as far as really flexible branching and merging goes, and it integrates flawlessly with Visual Studio.   Even some of our team members who had only used SourceSafe had no problems with it, as opposed to SVN.

Answer (score 1):

VisualSVN also costs (50$ per seat iirc), you can use AnkhSVN which is free alongside VisualSVN server.

There are quite a few [scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417355/is-there-a-way-to-migrate-sourcesafe-with-history-into-svn) people have written to migrate sourcesafe repo's into svn that retain history etc.

It is well worth the move.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a XXI century tool for version control, maybe **mercurial** is the one for you, you'll have a distributed version control and you'll be able to choose among many options for the development and release cycle.  You can install **tortoisehg**.  The integration with Visual Studio can be done via **visualhg**.  I [blogged](http://devnull.li/~ikks/DarkSideIsAllAroundUs/posts/visualstudiotips/) about that a time ago, I'm not able to put many links here yet, sorry.

With Mercurial you'll be able to use even outside your lan, there are plenty of options for publication and a central repository, or as I mentioned earlier, you can choose among many other aproximations for your source control.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered SourceGear Vault?

It will be a painless transition from VSS. They have a VSS plugin for Visual Studio, as well as a standalone client.

The [SourceGear Vault pricing page](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/pricing.html) will let you calculate license prices. For 10 users, it's averaging about $240 USD each.

Comment: That's too much money for source control

Comment: Guess you haven't seen the pricetag on TFS ;)